# Protobuf - serializetoarray not found in custom message type

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have an example message type for the protobuf defined in test.proto

```
message SearchRequest {
required string query = 1;
optional int32 page_number = 2;
optional int32 result_per_page = 3; 
}
```

in .cpp, I am trying to do something like:

```
SearchRequest req;
//some code
IoBuffer buf;
size_t len = req.byteSize();

req.SerializeToArray(buf, len);
```

But I do not see `SerializeToArray` in .pb.cc file, I could only find `SerializeWithCachedSizes`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the serialization and parsing methods are inherited from the base classes, [`google::protobuf::Message`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message) and [`google::protobuf::MessageLite`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite). They are all wrappers around the virtual methods `SerializeWithCachedSizes()`, `SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray()`, `ByteSize()`, and (for parsing) `MergePartialFromCodedStream()` (but you shouldn't use these virtual methods directly, except perhaps `ByteSize()`).